# Ошибка при парсинге JSON переменной

Tags: java, json

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема при парсинге переменной, использую библиотеку JSON-Simple.

Unexpected token END OF FILE at position

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=" + captchapublicKey);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
    org.json.simple.JSONObject JSONObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(input);
    System.out.println(JSONObject.get("challenge"));
}

System.exit(-1);
```

Вот json документ весь, который мне нужно парсить. Мне нужно спарсить переменную challenge.

```
var RecaptchaState = {
        challenge : '03AHJ_Vuul0sw1EYugvuRLkS3loEb1wv7kqBozHbvB7Loi54GRUCfU7ur56jjnSyxy4fVCUDPUfAGwoIRQca1QIpwPAm8Rl7S8g11ko7DMEhmnAJujLMa9ateHZrxICS_fmrpBqgqBObBrorrO3PsZGPbdOUVHiBYRaBo18TTIj9PbHHhhy-lvfkjj9Q69z7W8khIVxN5IqGLvnLaBAnzqZFU91azf01HX7Hel3Tp_HEt-vn_fPHyHKVYbYEicDeyH8v7ZA0l8HMg0iSDT_Yb3Lcs8CgkDDXTA4Q',
        timeout : 1800,
        lang : 'ru',
        server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
        site : '6LegWAEAAAAAANJcmtbLTuHlG7AbDzLPxvimCw_Z',
        error_message : '',
        programming_error : '',
        is_incorrect : false,
        rtl : false,
        t1 : 'Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9qcy90aC9fS1o2OXNyb1Ixcl91SmhTU2RaZ2IxYi1iQnkwdnpJZkhnOEVEN2wxcjRNLmpz',
        t2 : '',
        t3 : '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'
    };

    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: А JSON валидный приходит? Вижу, в случае ошибки Google может plain text вернуть

Comment: А как проверить?

Comment: Можно перейти по ссылке: `"http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=" + captchapublicKey` ...

Comment: Ваш подход сработает, только если весь json записан в одну строку (что не исключено), ведь вы каждую строку парсите как отдельный json-документ. Вы уверены, что всегда приходит одна строка?

Comment: Я добавил json-документ, в котором мне нужно спарсить переменную challenge, можете, пожалуйста, привести пример как её спарсить?

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ (ошибка была), попробуйте сейчас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То что вы приводите — это не JSON, это скрипт на языке JavaScript. Только то, что начинается с фигурной скобки и заканчивается фигурной скобкой, похоже на JSON. И то это не JSON, потому что по [стандарту](http://json.org/) строки должны быть заключены в двойные кавычки, и ключи должны быть в кавычках.

Если данные приходят конкретно в таком виде, проще из потока достать вторую строчку (`BufferedReader.readLine()`) и вытащить текст между двумя одинарными кавычками с помощью `String.substring`, `String.indexOf` и `String.lastIndexOf`. Или регулярным выражением, чтобы немного надёжнее было:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("challenge\\s*:\\s*\'([^\']+)\'");
String challenge = null;
while((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if(m.find()) {
        challenge = m.group(1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо `m.matches()` надо использовать `m.find()`. Либо изменить регулярку, чтобы она соответствовала строке целиком (пробелы в начале и запятая в конце).

Comment: @Roman, согласен, спасибо.

Comment: Ыыыыы! Парсинг рекурсивных грамматик регулярками — первый шаг к безалкогольному пиву!

Comment: @VladD, автор очевидно занимается грязными вещами: пытается разобрать документ неспецифицированного формата. Вы думаете, если прикрутить какой-нибудь парсер JavaScript, станет надёжнее? Завтра гугл может легко переименовать переменную `RecaptchaState` или поле `challenge`, ему никто не мешает это сделать.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Именно так! Поэтому единственное правильное решение — воспользоваться официальным API.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!)

Answer (score 3):

Рекапча может работать в режиме с отключенным js. Советую использовать его. Там будет форма в html-разметке и одна картинка.